# How to pass data stored in controller from one page to another

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm currently using one controller for my web app. Data is loaded from a JSON file and shown to the user via ng-repeat. When a user makes a selection, only data for the user's selection is in the scope.

I'd like to be able to keep the same scope data and use it across different web pages (or states using UI-Router).

I've looked into using ui-router but it seems like the controller would be refreshed with every state change.

I'd prefer to use ui-router due to design requirements.

Part of my controller code:

```
(function() {

"use strict";

angular
.module("parkit", ["ngMap"])
.controller("parkitController", function($scope, $rootScope, $http, 
parkitFactory, NgMap) {

    parkitFactory.getSpots().then(function(spots) {
      $scope.spots = spots.data;

    });

    $scope.showSpot = function(spot) {
      $scope.spot = spot;
    }

    });


})();
```

Factory code for loading JSON data:

```
(function() {

"use strict";

angular.module("parkit")
.factory("parkitFactory", function($http) {

    function getSpots() {
        return $http.get('/data/spots.json');
    }

    return {
    getSpots: getSpots
    }

    });

})();
```

Answer (score 2):

As it has been answered before, you can use a factory or service to keep track of the selected item(s). This would store the selected values in the instance of the service/factory and therefore would be lost if someone refreshes the page.

A more resilient, and in my opinion beautiful solution, would be to add the selected item(s) as state parameter in ui-router. Using this method, you will also be able to deep-link to certain selected states and if someone refreshes the page, the same items would still be selected, as you would add your state parameters in the url.

See URL Parameters in the documentation: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing

Answer (score 1):

You may probably create a new property in the factory function to keep track of the selected item.Set the property when user does a selection. Get the property in other components whereever you need to use the data.

Comment: Would this require a database? I plan on hosting this on github pages without any databases like Firebase or something similar.

Comment: No. This doesn't require a database unless you have to persist the data.
it will be like an in memory object in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

use **$rootScope** instead of **$scope** to save your data, That will allow you to use it anywhere in controllers of same domain.

example: **$rootScope.yourData = yourData;** and then you can assign  **$rootScope.yourData** to any controller in same domain.